# why the other part is not printed in the next line?

Tags: java, string, file

From the following code :

```
import java.io.*;

class fileTester {
  public static void main( String args[]) throws IOException {
    String string = "Suhail" + "\n" + "gupta";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( new File("break.txt"));
    byte[] data = string.getBytes();
    fos.write( data );
    fos.close();
  }
}
```

I expected the output to be :

**Suhail**

**Gupta**

int the file created *(i.e both the strings in a new line )* but the output is in a single line. *`Suhail gupta`*

Why is it so when i have used `\n` character in between the 2 Strings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't hard-code the new line character when writing to a file.  Use the OS-specific newline String instead:

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Also, rather than use a FileOutputStream to write raw bytes to a text file, why not wrap it in a PrintStream object so you can easily just use println(...) to do your newlines for you?

Comment: when i write `System.out.println("A" + "\n" + "B")` _A_ and _B_ get printed on new lines . How is that `\n` works here and not in the the code given ?

Comment: Suhail: When you "print" with System.out... you are printing to the console which is OS agnostic, and with the other you are printing to a file which is not OS agnostic.

Comment: i could not understand what you mean by OS **agnostic**

Comment: Java itself should work pretty much the same no matter what operating system (OS) it is running on. So Java isn't supposed to *care* which operating system is present -- it is (for the most part) OS agnostic. When you write to a text file, however, the file's format will depend on the operating system's requirements, and this is something that Java can't control. So here OS matters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using notepad to see the file.

End of line character varies from system to system. A more advanced text editor (v.g. Notepad++) will show it correctly, because it tries to find the system that this file was prepared for.

Usually, instead of using always "\n", use

```
 java.lang.System.getProperties().get("line.separator")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system is windows than you have to use `\r\n` for a new line, only `\n` won't work in windows, you can find more details [here](http://www.semiantics.com/?p=25)

Answer (score 0):

This is because for Windows new line is: \r\n. In other OS \n will be good

Answer (score 0):

when you need a new line, the best practice is to use the system newline string, by putting in System.getProperty("line.separator") where you want a line break.

That way, it will use the right new line for the platform you are making the file on (windows/mac/linux).